How to replace the default circle logo with my own logo?
I'm trying to replace a default circle logo (shown in the image) with my own custom logo on my website/app. I've tried searching online and following several guides, but nothing has worked so far. I'm not sure if it's an HTML or CSS issue.
My goal is to remove the existing logo and replace it with my logo image (my-logo.png). The logo is currently part of the interface, and I need help understanding where the logo might be defined and how to replace it effectively.
If it's defined in HTML, what changes should I make to the  tag? If it's a background image in CSS, what adjustments do I need to apply? I'm open to any suggestions or examples that can help me fix this.enter image description here
I'm trying to replace a default circle logo (shown in the image) with my own custom logo on my website/app. I've tried searching online and following several guides, but nothing has worked so far. I'm not sure if it's an HTML or CSS issue.
My goal is to remove the existing logo and replace it with my logo image (my-logo.png). The logo is currently part of the interface, and I need help understanding where the logo might be defined and how to replace it effectively.
If it's defined in HTML, what changes should I make to the  tag? If it's a background image in CSS, what adjustments do I need to apply? I'm open to any suggestions or examples that can help me fix this.

It is called favicon. A simple search with this keyword should give you the answer

"I've tried searching online and following several guides, but nothing has worked so far" did you try to open the site in private navigation or remove any cache after each change?

The favicon is in your Laravel project at ./public/favicon.ico
You can replace it with your own, perhaps using: https://www.favicon.cc/
Upload my-logo.png and download the converted .ico
The favicon is cached by the browser, so will need a hard refresh to notice the new favicon (Ctrl+Shift+R), or try in a new incognito/private browser window.

it is working. thank you have nice day

If you use lavavel-sanctum or laravel-breeze, you may find a file at resources/views/components/application-logo.blade.php. If so, that where your 'ico'-file is coming from. It's an svg-image.

may be it is possible. "./public/favicon.ico" this way working thank you for helping me. have a nice day
